# How to link this "contact us form" to my email address?

Tags: php, forms, email, contacts

I'm trying to link this form to my email address so i can receive it on my email.  can i start it with the mailto?

List item

```html
<form action="mailto:someone@example.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
  <div class="col-lg-7">
    <h3>Write To Us</h3>
    <br>
    <form role="form" action="#" method="post" enctype="plain">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name1">Your Name</label>
        <input type="name" name="Name" class="form-control" id="name1" placeholder="Your Name">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email1">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" name="Mail" class="form-control" id="email1" placeholder="Enter email">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Your Text</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" name="Message" rows="3"></textarea>
      </div>
      <br>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-large btn-success">SUBMIT</button>
```

Comment: This is all you can do with just HTML. You need to use PHP or some other sever side language and need SMTP server in order to "link" it with your email.

Comment: As mentioned in the comment above, you need to write some php that will handle the data and sending the mail, there's plenty of tutorials out there on how to do this, just google something simple as "php how to send mail"